# How to create Typescript decorator that sets all class properties as non-enumerable based on property name starting with "_"?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, class, oop

How do you get a Typescript class decorator to call a method that sets any property or method starting with an "_" as non-enumerable property (essentially making it private for serialization purposes)?

Imagine there's a class that's a base class which every other class in my application will extend from:

```
class Base {
     constructor(data: any){
        Object.assign(this, data)
     }

     _setNonEnumerableProperties(){
        Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
            if(key[0] === '_')
                Object.defineProperty(this, key, { enumerable: false })
        })
     }
}
```

And then I have a User class like this:

```
@nonEnumerablePrivateMembers
class User extends Base {
     public name: string
     public email: string
     private _active: boolean
}
```

And I create and JSON stringify a User instance like this:

```
const user = new User({name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com', _active: false})
const jsonUser = JSON.stringify(user)
console.log(jsonUser)
```

I expect the output to be this:

```
{ "name": "John", "email": "john@example.com" }
```

and not this:

```
{ "name": "John", "email": "john@example.com", "_active": false }
```

Note that it doesn't include the `_active` property.

I need to know how to write `nonEnumerablePrivateMembers` decorator that would call the `_setNonEnumerableProperties` method on the Base class upon a new instance of the extended class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not make the decorator define a [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) method that deals with that instead modifying the property descriptor of each private member just to affect serialization behavior?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts mainly because all libraries don't necessarily use JSON as serialization method (for example DB drivers, etc.) and also I want the ability to pass class instances as a DTO.

Comment: You're assuming every database driver implementation will only consider enumerable properties, which is brittle at best, but almost certainly an incorrect assumption. Most drivers ship with their own model classes which you should use as documented, rather than relying on property enumerability. Reflection methods like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` will gladly ignore the `enumerable` property in the property descriptor.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's very true I agree. I guess the DB drivers I am using don't necessarily use JSON as a serialization method. Also, for me, the ability to use class instances as DTO is a huge plus. But good point, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the constructor appears to work as intended:

```
interface Class<T> {
  new(...args: any[]): T
}

function nonEnumerablePrivateMembers<T extends Class<Base>>(cls: T): T {
  return class extends cls {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      this._setNonEnumerableProperties();
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?experimentalDecorators=true&target=7#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1rAPYDsIBcAnAV2Hy0IAoATMfMALmjBwE8BKFdDaAeQCMAVgjIA6SBACWAcxyV8AC0kQANNFr123AL6puAfQgJ8AOVwBRHMQC2CQmH4gEABUJYADnfySEESpzQePiERfFEAawRWP0VldlEAMwpzMGAFSkjWaABeAD4uIIxJBOgMqIBtAAYAXRzs7OgAcn1GrUKeAWExagQEyRwXN09CfFZ5JVVoTLVkaAQrW3tHBCYEsBAjaG02nm2dVF1Ufvw7NeAkAGFwKAAeABV8wOgBgHdKUQ+wQmkIJhZWcrVdhMO4HPQJYg4MiSXDPCwLOwOJyuSQANzoCAAsghrPw7BB7nMAB4nHDUGBXCQ3eBGXK5SigX7QO7A5kFaBOfCYDYAJhy3IkxNJ5O5MCeGGweCIpHIVA+4m+TP+gIC3CCEGIw3en0V7AA3GqeLEIKJDMYzDhLDZEctXB4vD4-PrDboMK7gl0wj0+gM7cNRpRDYyeWpGjgwLZGjNoOiQMQVqLROHbGoXoRJPRlqt1pttgbuIRjMRCDhRTyDYcAAI4eHWpbI9Pok7Y3H41CgQUAVSMhCF8xFNKQT3cxEckmAzwjCYI6Zw0gNGBHY4nOLAkhATBn-Xn3HcjYx0H0qW8qIT-CwWCcLAreklBGgxB7-Ne0G7dkos2TCcaACksAocCjOZrDXDcmkEf8cErBAiQjdwnFEbBrCAo9oVPbMNiQPY7y5QQIFwN9ewaH8AGVeBMUQtznYoxkfOwtDvS8EFEEAsGkSg8IInsGNwfCENY9i6MIRDeOlMgKCTKceLwJiWLYyghOgfoCBYc4sBKQitCAA)

Comment: Much cleaner!  Nice.

Comment: This is a good solution, however, the class that's generated when creating a new instance of User is an anonymous class. How can I maintain the class name as `User` and not shown to me as `class_1` for example?

Comment: After some research, `Object.defineProperty(this.constructor, 'name', { value: cls.name, writable: false })` inside the constructor does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @ultd: nice, I've added your suggestion to the PG

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone with better TypeScript skills can modify this to be a bit cleaner, but based on the [TypeScript decorator docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) you can have something like this:

```
function fixEnumerables<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  return class extends constructor {
    constructor(...data: any[]) {
      super(data);
      Object.assign(this, data[0]);
      Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
        if (key[0] === "_") {
          console.log(`Freezing "${key}"`);
          Object.defineProperty(this, key, { enumerable: false });
        }
      });
    }
  };
}

@fixEnumerables
class User {
  public name: string;
  public email: string;
  private _active: boolean;
  constructor(data: any) {}
}

const x = new User({ name: "Sam", email: "email@example.com", _active: false });
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));

// Output
// Freezing "_active"
// {"name":"Sam", "email": "email@example.com"}
```

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ddcxv1)